# Flex download file from remote server

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

With Air, i try to load file from remote server and open the file with default application.

```
private function getRemoteCourr(PathFichier:String, FileName:String):void  {
    urlStream = new URLStream();
    fileData  = new ByteArray();
    var urlRemoteCourr:String = new urlManager().urlCourriersPat();

    var PathFichierGlob: String = urlRemoteCourr+PathFichier;
    var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(urlRemoteCourr);
    urlStream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:*):void {fileLoaded(e,FileName)});
    urlStream.load(urlReq);
}

private function fileLoaded(event:Event, PathFichier:String):void  {
    urlStream.readBytes(fileData, 0, urlStream.bytesAvailable);
    var file:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath(PathFichier);
    var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    fileStream.openAsync(file, FileMode.WRITE);
    fileStream.writeBytes(fileData, 0, fileData.length);
    fileStream.close();

    file.openWithDefaultApplication();
}
```

With this part of code, a file is creating on document directory (as I want), but the content isn't original file content.
For a word document, the new content is

```
Index of /MyApp/LinkMySQL/Customer/Courriers

Name
Last modified
Size
Description


Parent Directory 
    -    

0/ 
13-Feb-2012 20:24
```

Instead of a word document with image and text.

Comment: Umm. You're doing an asynchronous open, but then attempting to write on the very next line.  If you need to do the asynchronous open, shouldn't you be writing your bytes only after a COMPLETE event has been fired?  Or just use the synchronous open operation instead.  I don't know if that's the issue--just an observation.

Comment: That sure looks a lot like a directory index, are you positive your the url you're loading from is correct? I would guess you're missing the actual file name on the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that could be happening is you are downloading the directory listing instead of the actual file. e.g. `http://www.myserver.com/files` instead of `http://www.myserver.com/files/myDocument.doc`

You could add a check for that before you start the download

However, If you look at your code, you will see

```
private function getRemoteCourr(PathFichier:String, FileName:String):void  {
    urlStream = new URLStream();
    fileData  = new ByteArray();
    var urlRemoteCourr:String = new urlManager().urlCourriersPat();

    var PathFichierGlob: String = urlRemoteCourr+PathFichier;
    //var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(urlRemoteCourr);
    //!!!!REQUESTING ONLY urlRemoteCourr
    //INSTEAD DO THIS:
    var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(PathFichierGlob);
    urlStream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:*):void {fileLoaded(e,FileName)});
    urlStream.load(urlReq);
}
```

Oh, and just as a passing note, AS3 variable names do not begin with an upper case letter (like you have used). Class names do. That is the convention.

Answer (score 1):

Find below the solution

```
public class fMoveCopy
{

    private var urlStream:URLStream;  
    private var fileData:ByteArray = new ByteArray(); 
    private var fileName:String;
    private var fileLocal:File;

    public function fMoveCopy()
    {
    }


    public function getFileRemote(pathRemote:String, fileNameR:String):void  
    {  
        urlStream = new URLStream();
        var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(pathRemote);  
        urlStream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);  
        urlStream.load (urlReq);  
        fileName = fileNameR;
    }  

    private function loaded(event:Event):void  
    {  
        urlStream.readBytes (fileData, 0, urlStream.bytesAvailable);  
        resolveFile(fileName);  
    }  

    private function resolveFile(pathLocal:String):void  
    {  
        fileLocal = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(pathLocal);  
        var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();  
        fileStream.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, fileClosed);  
        fileStream.openAsync(fileLocal, FileMode.WRITE);  
        fileStream.writeBytes(fileData, 0, fileData.length);  
        fileStream.close();  
    }  

    private function fileClosed(event:Event):void  
    {  

        fileLocal.openWithDefaultApplication();
    }  




}
```